# A Question about Time Dilation and different observers

Tags: speed-of-light, time-dilation

This is a question about time dilation and different observers. Say you had two observers. One on earth and the other one traveling around 20% of the speed of light. The observer on earth will age faster than the observer traveling at 20% the speed of light.

The question is, will the observer traveling at 20% the speed of light travel into the person that's on earth's future? Say 30 years go by for the person on earth but only 5 years pass for the person traveling at 20% the speed of light.

Is the person traveling at 20% the speed of light just in another reference frame and the person on earth will still age and experience 30 years passing or will the person on earth and the one traveling at 20% of the speed of light both experience 5 years passing but the person traveling at 20% the speed of light will just end up in the person on earth's fututre?

If I understand this correctly, the person traveling at 20% the speed of light isn't traveling into the future of the person that's on earth, their just both in different reference frames relative to each other so the person on earth will have experienced 30 years and the person traveling at 20% of the speed of light will experience 5 years. Is this correct?

Also, does the rate entropy increases slow down as you move closer towards the speed of light?